# Parshat Zachor - Do you need to understand or just hear

Tags: halacha, hebrew, four-parshiot, motzi-yedei-chovato

The responsibility of reading Zachor is in order to remember to wipe out Amalek. Therefore we read it annually.

Does someone who hears the words of Zachor, but does not understand them, still fulfill the mitzvah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Halichos Shlomo Perek 18 Note 3 (Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach) you are Yotzei, however the Moadim UZmanim Chelek 2 Siman 165 & 167 (Rabbi Moshe Sternbach) holds you are not Yotzei.